# Qt 4.8.4 application crashes on Windows Vista while quitting

Tags: qt, windows-vista, stack-trace, segmentation-fault

I have a Qt application which intermittently crashes while exiting on a Windows Vista machine (it works fine on Mac & Windows XP, need to try more on other Windows versions). I am doing a QApplication cleanup on exit and getting the following stack trace on crash. Please let me know if anyone gets any clue what I might be doing wrong.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to thread 876.0x15f0]
0x69dfb912 in QEventDispatcherWin32Private::unregisterTimer (this=0x14cdf9b8,
t=0x1a1f6868, closingDown=true) at kernel/qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:620
(gdb) bt
#0  0x69dfb912 in QEventDispatcherWin32Private::unregisterTimer (
    this=0x14cdf9b8, t=0x1a1f6868, closingDown=true)
    at kernel/qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:620
#1  0x69dfd479 in QEventDispatcherWin32::closingDown (this=0x14cdf998)
    at kernel/qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:1115
#2  0x69cd7ff2 in QThreadPrivate::finish (arg=0x14cddb48, lockAnyway=true)
    at thread/qthread_win.cpp:376
#3  0x69cd7ec8 in QThreadPrivate::start (arg=0x14cddb48)
    at thread/qthread_win.cpp:348
#4  0x766f2599 in wcstombs () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#5  0x766f26b3 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x7624d309 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive ()
    from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#7  0x774b16c3 in ntdll!RtlInitializeNtUserPfn ()
    from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#8  0x774b1696 in ntdll!RtlInitializeNtUserPfn ()
    from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Do you have some thread in which you use timer? Also it would be helpful if you provide debug output of your application.

Comment: Did you actively delete any object that you handled over to Qt? Qt takes Ownership of most elements you pass to it (i.e. Widget children etc.). Another reason might be a uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Yes, I am using timer in some other threads. But I clean them up before the thread finishes. I didn't see any debug/fatal/warning messages (through qDebug or similar) being printed though.